# Define Loud and Soft Volume of Sound

Tags: audio, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

Analog_Read() in Arduino range from 0-1023. 
**If I'm using a Piezo Buzzer**, how I can define from range 0-1023 that the **sound I read are Loud or Soft?**
I'm already testing it *(basic Piezo Buzzer and Arduino Uno Serial Configuration)* and show it using Serial Monitor, but the value are random and not in some range to define Loud and Soft Volume of sound my system read.
**I need to define limit range of loud and soft volume of sound that my system read using piezo buzzer and arduino.**
Please click the link to show the schematic design:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWYhC.png

Comment: How is the buzzer connected to the Arduino?

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield , the buzzer connected to Analog Pin 0 and connected using 1M Ohm Resistor

Comment: Can you add a circuit diagram to your question to make it clearer?

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield , please click link above for diagram

Comment: That setup works fine for me. I'd recommend testing the analog pin using a potentiometer to see if it actually works. If so then there may be a fault with your piezo element.